# Using google oauth2 for spreadsheets getting an error "google.sheets is not a function"

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

`var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
                      ^
TypeError: google.sheets is not a function`

I am using this startup tutorial [Node.js Quickstart for Google spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). 
Is anyone else also facing this problem?

Comment: Your situation might be the same to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816324/gmail-api-quickstart-failing-at-google-gmailv1

Comment: Again thank you so much for help @Tanaike

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is resolved. This issue was coming because of Google's API version v4 :

Need to use like `var { google } = require("googleapis")`

Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: Same error encountered even with this change